# What are some ways to prove that centripetal force is a center seeking force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

What are some examples of cases that illustrate the center-seeking behavior of centripetal force? I cannot find any examples of the center-seeking behavior of object in a circular path without any other source of force such as tension or another external force. In these cases, how are we able to say that the force is center-seeking, it seems to me that it can also be an outward force.

In the case of object following semi-circular paths such as parabolic motion and in a bowl, the "center" seeking force is clearly demonstrated, but I cannot find such examples in the case of complete revolutions.

Comment: If there is no tension/gravity/other force, an object will not take a circular path. There is no example of center-seeking behavior of an object in circular motion that does *not* involve some kind of force - that *is* the centripetal force that results in the circular path in the first place.

Comment: This the definition of centripetal.  If it is not center seeking is not centripetal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot find any examples of the center-seeking behavior of object in a circular path without any other source of force such as tension or another external force.

Note sure what you are expecting to find here. The "behaviour" or motion of an object is determined by the net force acting on it. Newton's First Law tell us that if the net force acting on an object is zero then it moves in a straight line at constant speed - we can include a stationary object in this category, since its speed is zero.

If an object is not moving in a straight line at constant speed - if it moves in a  circle for example - then there must be some non-zero force acting on it. Newton's Second Law tells us that the net force must be in the same direction as the instantaneous change in the object's direction (which is its acceleration).

If an object is moving in a circle at constant speed then a simple geometrical argument shows its acceleration vector is always pointing towards the centre of the circle. Hence the net force on the object must point towards the centre of the circle - this is what we call "centripetal force".

There can be various sources for the centripetal force - tension in a string, friction on a flat bend, horizontal component of normal force on a banked bend, electromagnetic force, gravity etc. And there could be several forces acting on the object at the same time - when the Moon is between the Earth and the Sun, the Sun's gravity is "outwards" but the "inward" force of the Earth's gravity is greater, so the net force is "inwards", towards the Earth. But you cannot have circular motion with *no* forces acting on an object at all.

Comment: Also worth noting that if the object is moving around a circle faster and faster, there is a tangential component to the force. In that case, it doesn't point at the center. Similar if it is slowing down.

Comment: This post does not address the question, and I don't think Newton's second law can be used to explain non inertial frames.

Comment: @ten1o Ok, I should have said "in a Newtonian inertial reference frame" throughout. Obviously Newton's Laws do not apply in a non-inertial reference frame (by definition of non-inertial). Unless you introduce pseudo-forces such as centrifugal force, Coriolis force etc. which just causes confusion.